# c# Surpass double limit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, double, size, limit

Developing a game, where all values grow exponential, i've encountered some limit for a player, but what I want is to make game almost infinite.
I use `Double` type for storing all values, as it has `±1.7 × 10^308` range.

Actualy i have a bunch of questions:

1. How can I check if var is going to overflow on some operation?
2. How can I manage and operate a complex value, that can hold more than `double.MaxValue` range?
3. According to q2 - how can I serialize this value? (game save-load)

Example of some overflow operation, that may occur in late-game:

```
a = 1.79E+308;
b = 1.78E+308;
c = a+b; // game freeze.
```

Comment: There are no more than 10^82 atoms in the universe. Do you *really* need numbers above 10^308? It seems... excessive.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, well, it's always not enough for humanity) Seriously saying, people like big numbers, even if they don't make sense. I can probably workaround by showing values to player more than they actual are. Right now its hard for me to well design all formulas that game have, the graphs like `1.06^x` work well untill x gets bigger than `~10^4`

Comment: Maybe instead you should not try to display/calculate the whole number but work with human readable values like 1000 -> 1 T; 1000T -> 1 M; etc...

Comment: @derHugo , Im doing this right now - 100 000 = 1a, 10^10 = 1b... etc, its for user friendly display, but for calculations i must use actual double value... or no?

Answer (score 3):

Overflow isn't your only problem. `System.Double` values aren't evenly distributed. Your game logic also has to be robust to lack of floating-point precision at large values:

```
        double a = 1e100;
        double b = 1e100 + 1;
        if (a == b)
        {
            Debug.Log("Yup, they're equal.");
        }
```

Issues like this famously gave rise to the [Far Lands](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Far_Lands) in Minecraft.

There are numeric formats for dealing with arbitrarily large numbers, like [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger), but these are intended more for specialized mathematical uses, and probably not suitable performance-wise for a game.

There are various tricks for overcoming issues with large floating-point values in games, like doing calculations relative to a local reference point. If your main goal is to show a very large number to the player, then it's almost certainly going to be easier to 'fake it' by artifically enlarging the number you display.

Comment: Thanks for that info! Well, when values in the game reach big numbers, i don't really care about precision on small values, because those numbers are growing even bigger by exponent. My main goal is to have a nice formulas, that are growing exponential and provide player more and more challenge every time he act. Simple example - costs are growing exponential, while income is a linear function. To make game infinite, I allow player to reset his income function, so every reset, player will generate more money.

Comment: BigInteger works just fine for games. You just have to be aware that they're `Objects` and take space on the Heap (and thus need to be garbage collected) and that some operations (e.g. square root) are going to be expensive. But addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and comparisons are cheap. In the idle game that I recently finished up I had a bigger problem in a section of Unity specific code than I did with BigInt.

Comment: @Draco18s, thanks! May I know what to be aware of using BigInt and what problems you faced using BigInt in Unity? As I understand, all my in-game calculations (may reach above 2000/min later on) will become much expensive, because of Pow functions everywhere

Comment: @Rdq Basically, any time you can cache a value, cache it. For example [I have some caching here](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/game/PlayerInfo.cs#L171-202), those values being used hundreds of times a second and only resetting rarely. Some more [here](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/game/Main.cs#L309), getting recalculated every 10 seconds.